# Changing font of entire text from hovering over nth:child

Tags: html, css

When I try to change the font-family + text-shadow of a text from hovering over an n:th child, it doesn't seem to work right as it needs to me hover over another area for it to be able to change styles. It works fine when I don't have it change font-family when hovered on though.

```css
.hero-name div {
    font-family: 'Train One', cursive;
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 10vmin;
}

.hero-name div:first-of-type:hover, .hero-name div:first-of-type:hover ~ div {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-shadow: 0 0.1vmin 0 #dba1a1, 0 0.2vmin 0 #d89999, 0 0.3vmin 0 #d59292,
      0 0.4vmin 0 #d28a8a, 0 0.5vmin 0 #cf8383, 0 0.6vmin 0 #cd7c7c,
      0 0.7vmin 0 #ca7474, 0 0.8vmin 0 #c76d6d, 0 0 0.5vmin rgb(230 139 139 / 5%),
      0 -0.1vmin 0.3vmin rgb(230 139 139 / 20%),
      0 0.9vmin 9vmin rgb(230 139 139 / 30%),
      0 1.2vmin 1.2vmin rgb(230 139 139 / 30%),
      0 1.5vmin 1.5vmin rgb(230 139 139 / 30%);
}

.hero-name div:nth-child(2):hover, .hero-name div:nth-child(2):hover ~ div {
    font-family: 'Anton', sans-serif;
    color: #d9d9d9;
    text-shadow: -1px -1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,.1), 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}
```

```html
        <!-- Banner Section -->
        <section id="banner">
            <div class="hero-name">
                <div>Y</div>
                <div>O</div>
                <div>U</div>
                <div>R</div>
                <div> </div>
                <div>N</div>
                <div>A</div>
                <div>M</div>
                <div>E</div>
            <div class="hero-pro">
                <h2>Title Here</h2>
            </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

Additionally, how do I make it so the first child is also changed when selecting the second child? I know '~' only affects the ones AFTER nth:child.

Comment: Your code is working in the snippet

Comment: @ProsyArceno The font-style I am using (Train-One) for the divs does not show load with the code snippet and I think the letter width of that font messes with the letter width of the next font, making its hover location somewhere else.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use CSS Combinators to apply styles on elements before the hovered one. However using a little of JavaScript you can achieve the desired.

So, you can listen for the `mouseover` event on the `#hero-home` and get which element is current hovered, then you just need to assign it to the parent element to be able to somehow apply a CSS style to it.

See code snippet example:

```js
var banner = document.getElementById("hero-name");
banner.addEventListener('mouseover', myFunction, false);

function myFunction ( e ) {
  //get current hovered position on the node
  var curHover = Array.from(e.currentTarget.children).indexOf(e.target);
  if( curHover >= 0 ){
    banner.setAttribute('data-hovered', curHover);
  }else{
    //reset data-hovered to fall back into initial style
    //banner.removeAttribute('data-hovered');
  } 
}
```

```css
.hero-name div {
    font-family: 'Train One', cursive;
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 10vmin;
}

.hero-name[data-hovered="0"] > div {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-shadow: 0 0.1vmin 0 #dba1a1, 0 0.2vmin 0 #d89999, 0 0.3vmin 0 #d59292,
      0 0.4vmin 0 #d28a8a, 0 0.5vmin 0 #cf8383, 0 0.6vmin 0 #cd7c7c,
      0 0.7vmin 0 #ca7474, 0 0.8vmin 0 #c76d6d, 0 0 0.5vmin rgb(230 139 139 / 5%),
      0 -0.1vmin 0.3vmin rgb(230 139 139 / 20%),
      0 0.9vmin 9vmin rgb(230 139 139 / 30%),
      0 1.2vmin 1.2vmin rgb(230 139 139 / 30%),
      0 1.5vmin 1.5vmin rgb(230 139 139 / 30%);
}

.hero-name[data-hovered="1"] > div,
.hero-name[data-hovered="5"] > div{
    font-family: 'Anton', sans-serif;
    color: #d9d9d9;
    text-shadow: -1px -1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,.1), 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}
.hero-name[data-hovered="2"] > div,
.hero-name[data-hovered="6"] > div{
    font-family: 'Times', sans-serif;
    color: #ff0000;
    text-shadow: -1px -1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,.1), 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}
.hero-name[data-hovered="3"] > div,
.hero-name[data-hovered="7"] > div{
    font-family: 'Lucida Handwriting', sans-serif;
    color: #fff000;
    text-shadow: -1px -1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,.1), 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}
.hero-name[data-hovered="4"] > div,
.hero-name[data-hovered="8"] > div{
    font-family: 'Calibri', sans-serif;
    color: #ggg0000;
    text-shadow: -1px -1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,.1), 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}
```

```html
<!-- Banner Section -->
<section id="banner">
    <div class="hero-name" id="hero-name">
        <div>Y</div>
        <div>O</div>
        <div>U</div>
        <div>R</div>
        <div> </div>
        <div>N</div>
        <div>A</div>
        <div>M</div>
        <div>E</div>
        <div class="hero-pro">
            <h2>Title Here</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```